# Calling CPanel API from a different server

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have 6 VPS' with CPanel / WHM on. I currently have an admin section on each one that I use to create accounts and start some Crons. I would like to manage all this from one server but I can't connect using my script unless I use it on the server I am calling it for.

The error I get is: `curl_exec threw error "couldn't connect to host"` which I presume means the connection is actually being blocked. I have added a firewall rule for my admin server's IP but that doesn't help.

What do I need to allow in order to use the API cross server?

p.s I am using User / Pass authentication with PHP.

EDIT: Ok I can connect when changing the port to 2087 but get access denied messages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK sorted it.

I needed to change the port I was connecting on to 2087 (from 2082) and use the WHM root login credentials.

Comment: Well that's 3 hours of my life wasted because of a port issue... Thanks!

Comment: @AaronHatton - No problem, glad it helped after all this time :)